# Any way to get the T-SQL generated by SSMS Script Wizard?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I'm trying to script out all my stored procedures, and it's very easy to do in SSMS by right clicking my database, then going to Tasks -> Generate Scripts.  I set my options and all is good.

I would like to get the actual T-SQL that the script wizard is executing so that I don't have to go through and select all of my options every single time I want to do it.  I want to just open the script and hit run.  Is there a way to copy the script that the wizard itself is executing? Or do I just have to do it manually every time?

Comment: Run a profiler trace. It will show you what SSMS is doing.

Comment: Are you open to a very simple powershell script for this?

Comment: @JNK If that's what you got, hit me.

Comment: @Jason Posted, let me know if you need more help with it.  It's actually pretty intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a pretty simple powershell script using the SMO Framework.  You will need to have SQL Server Management Studio installed for the framework to get picked up.  You should look into this further, but the basic framework will be:

```
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO")

$srv = new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server" 'MyServer'

$db = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database"
$db = $srv.Databases['MyDatabase']

$scr = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter"
$scr.Server = $srv

$scr.options.filename = 'C:\SomeFolder\MyExports.SQL'

$db.StoredProcedures | where-object {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $False} | %{$scr.Script($_)}
```

You may need to alter some additional options.  [MSDN has a pretty thorough overview of the framework here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557.aspx)

Essentially the above will script out all the stored procs in a database to whatever file you specify.  SMO is the framework that SSMS uses so it should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're after is "script all procedures," and it's a one-time thing, you can open Object Explorer Details in Management Studio, highlight Stored Procedures in Object Explorer, then Ctrl + A, right-click, script as > ...

If you want a slightly more automated way, there are several schema comparison products on the market so that you don't have to care about the script that Management Studio uses to generate the script for a single object. As a bonus, it will be much easier to synchronize other, more complicated objects - just try to generate the script for a table yourself, and you will see it is no picnic. I go over many options in [this blog post](http://www.onetooneglobal.com/otocorporate-posts/2009/06/01/the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/).

Comment: Not sure if you have tried PS yet for this, but it works great, Aaron.  It'll do dependencies and everything else you might need.  Let me know if you are curious and I can send you some sample scripts.

Comment: @JNK For a `CREATE TABLE` with column constraints, default values, triggers, alias types, etc.? How about permissions? My point is that you *can* do this yourself with PowerShell, but to get it right and fully complete is going to be a significant amount of effort (unless your tables are very simple).

Comment: @JNK I'd be happy to be mistaken, and PS may very well handle all the nuances I could foresee. Another complication: what if some of the objects already exist at the destination, and are in the same or a different state? I suspect PS won't be able to compare two databases and script the deltas (which is probably the more tedious part of this exercise in any event).

Comment: Hypothetically anything you can do in SSMS you can do in SMO and PS.  For the more comparisons it does get a bit trickier, though.  I'm not proposing rewriting SQL Compare  but you can do some pretty cool stuff pretty easily.

Comment: No question. Wasn't suggesting PS wasn't a good way to play around, or that you can't do everything here and more, just that it can become increasingly tedious to cover all the bases.